# How to declare a static string array in Java?

Tags: java

I have a Java program that has two functions and a static string array. Can anybody tell me how to declare a static string array in Java?

Comment: This question is unclear. Do you want to initialise it to something, if so what? Otherwise how do you intend to initialise it? Do you mean `static` (the java keyword) or do you mean constant?

Comment: Use java documentation.

Comment: @Ankur that sounds harsh for a beginner. Everyone was a beginner and everyone does hope to hear more motivating words during that time.

Answer (score 42):

To initialise an array at construction time you can specify a list values in curly braces:

```
private static final String[] STRING_ARRAY = {"foo", "bar", "baz"};
```

In my example I have assumed that you won't want to change the instance of array and so have declared it `final`.  You still would be able to update individual entries like so:

```
 array[0] = "1";
```

But you won't be able to replace the array with a different one completely.  If the values are going to change a lot - especially if the number of values are going to change - then it may be worth considering using `List` instead.

Comment: OP didn't say anything about final though.

Comment: @MagnusTengdahl - good point, the `final` went in also out of habit.  I have extended the answer to explain this choice.

Answer (score 12):

```
public static String[] stringArray = new String[size]; // give some "size"
```

OR

```
public static String[] stringArray = {"String1","String2","String3"};
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static String[] array ={"foo","bar"};
```